# Почему не установлены зависимости, хотя пакет есть?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, mocha

Пытаюсь настроить модульное тестирование во `Vuejs`. Установил все необходимые пакеты(**@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha**, **@vue/test-utils**, **extract-text-webpack-plugin**, **chai**,**mocha**, **mochapack**, **webpack-dev-server**, **webpack**). Вот полный список:

```
├── @fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.9.0
├── @vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha@3.10.0
├── @vue/test-utils@1.0.0-beta.29
├── ajv@6.10.0
├── axios@0.18.1
├── bootstrap@4.3.1
├── chai@4.2.0
├── cross-env@5.2.0
├── cyrillic-to-translit-js@2.2.0
├── d3@5.9.2
├── d3-3d@0.0.9
├── dayjs@1.8.14
├── expect@24.8.0
├── extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2
├── gantt-elastic@1.0.3
├── imagemin@5.3.1
├── jquery@3.4.1
├── jsbarcode@3.11.0
├── jsdom@15.1.1
├── jsdom-global@3.0.2
├── laravel-echo@1.5.4
├── laravel-mix@2.1.14
├── lodash@4.17.15
├── makerjs@0.14.0
├── material-design-icons-iconfont@3.0.3
├── mocha@6.2.0
├── mochapack@1.1.3
├── moment@2.24.0
├── node-sass@4.12.0
├── opentype.js@1.1.0
├── pdfmake@0.1.51
├── popper.js@1.15.0
├── sass-loader@7.1.0
├── socket.io-client@2.2.0
├── sortablejs@1.9.0
├── vue@2.6.10
├── vue-cookie@1.1.4
├── vue-hotel-datepicker@2.7.1
├── vue-router@3.0.6
├── vue-template-compiler@2.6.10
├── vuedraggable@2.21.0
├── vuelidate@0.7.4
├── vuetify@1.5.0
├── vuex@3.1.1
├── vuex-router-sync@5.0.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@4.39.1
└── webpack-dev-server@3.8.0
```

Следовал [инструкции](https://dev.to/tuandm/how-to-test-vue-components-with-laravel-mix-and-mocha-3kgc) (помимо зависимостей указанных в инструкции, доставить пришлось ещё **extract-text-webpack-plugin**). Но получаю ошибку:

> npm ERR! peer dep missing: webpack@^3.1.0, required by extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2
>   npm ERR! peer dep missing: webpack@^3.1.0, required by extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2

Как мне её победить?

Comment: Это вопрос-самоответ? Дело в том, что в инструкции рассмотрен схожий пример о равных зависимостях (peerDependencies).

Comment: @РустамГимранов нет, это вопрос. На данный момент она решилась, но я не понял как. Я выполнил две команды `fix audit --force` и `npm remove extract-text-webpack-plugin`. Правда сломался, `vue-loader`. Буду пробовать воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: [`extract-text-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) - этот пакет устарел. А у него в [peerDependencies](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/blob/master/package.json#L64) как раз числится `"webpack": "^3.1.0"`